# Registering systematic review in Prospero

Tags: publications, peer-review, review-articles

I have recently submitted a systematic review (SR) to a journal. One of the reviewers pointed out, that my SR was not registered in [Prospero](http://www.crd.york.ac.uk/PROSPERO/), an international prospective register of systematic reviews. While I agree it would have been of good practice to register my SR, my current understanding is that registration of SR is not yet mandatory¹.

How can I address this reviewer’s remark?

---

<sup>¹[Booth A, Clarke M, Dooley G, et al. The nuts and bolts of PROSPERO: an international prospective register of systematic reviews. Systematic Reviews. 2012;1:2](http://dx.doi.org/10.1186/2046-4053-1-2)</sup>

Comment: If you don't think it's mandatory, and you don't want to do it, just say it's intentionnal ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Gautier C. The thing is, even if I wanted to register now, it probably makes less sense as I should have done it before starting my SR... Well, lesson learned...

Comment: Hum I see. But if the reviewer is saying it, that means he thinks you may want to register in it ?

Comment: Thanks Gautier C. From my understanding, this database is used when you plan to undertake a SR, in order to avoid having duplicate SR and to reduce reporting bias. I am not sure if registration in this database makes sense once the SR is finished and submitted for publication. But I am going to double check this. Thanks Gautier C for your valuable input!

Comment: I will create an answer based of what you said, hoping maybe people will add some infos to my answer ;)

Answer (score -1):

First of all, If you don't think it's mandatory, and you don't want to do it, just say **it's intentionnal**.

Since, as you said in comments, this database is apparently used when you plan to undertake a SR, it would have **no value for you** to register in it, since you are already in SR.

But you may **ask the reviewer** why he got the urge for saying that , and if he thinks it would be interesting for you to register on it anyway.

Comment: I do not work in a discipline that can use PROSPERO, but personally I do not find appropriate to ask the reviewer why "he got the urge for saying that". The fact that this research was not pre-registered automatically makes it less trustworthy than a pre-registered one, so to me it looks like a meaningful remark to make in a review. It's not something the author can address now, but it is a perfectly normal part of a thorough evaluation of the strengths and weaknesses of the paper.